# Java Sort list of objects by name but one object should remain always in the top

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

```
class Manager
{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Manager(int id, String name)
    {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
}

List<Manager> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add(new Manager(1, "Robert"));
names.add(new Manager(2, "Paul"));
names.add(new Manager(3, "None"));
names.add(new Manager(4, "Nancy"));
names.add(new Manager(4, "Nancy"));

names.stream().sorted(
                Comparator.comparing(n->n.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());


List<String> names = new List<String>();
names.add("Robert");
names.add("Paul");
names.add("None");
names.add("Nancy");
names.add("Nancy");


names.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I need to sort a list of strings in Java 8 which I can do it easily using below logic but I want to display the None in the below list at top always. The result has to be. I need to obtain a sort order for the List of Managers objects

```
None
Jhon
Nancy
Paul
```

My code:

```
List<String> names = new List<String>();
names.add("Robert");
names.add("Paul");
names.add("None");
names.add("Nancy");
names.add("Jhon");


names.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

string needs to be on the first place always.

Comment: add custom comparator

Comment: it will be easy if you change `None` to `null` using `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())`

Comment: Can you just insert None as the first object after it is sorted?

Comment: @tim.paetz I would guess there might be a dynamic number of "None" entries in the list (0 to XXX) and the code above is just an example.

Comment: there is no `new List<String>()` in java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
List<Manager> sorted = names.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Manager::getName,
              Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("None"))
                        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

to sort into a new list or use

```
names.sort(Comparator.comparing(Manager::getName,
              Comparator.comparing((String s) -> !s.equals("None"))
                        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

to sort in-place, which is possible with a mutable list like `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you it works great. how do we do we apply the same logic to display None at the bottom of the list?

Comment: You can put them at the end instead of beginning by simply removing the not (`!`) operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in a comparator object to the `sorted` intermediate method defining your criteria like so:

```
List<String> resultSet = 
         names.stream()
              .sorted((e, a) -> "None".equals(e) ? -1:
                              "None".equals(a) ? 1 : e.compareTo(a))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you for your input how can I do the above logic on Manager object?

Comment: This comparator is invalid, if both arguments are `"None"`, it should return `0`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to filter out `"None"`, and pre-pend it to a sorted list:

```
List<String> ordered = Stream.concat(
    names.stream().filter(s -> s.equals("None"))
,   names.stream().filter(s -> !s.equals("None")).sorted()
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/1SKCJ5)

Comment: Thank you how do we sort the list of manager objects with the same behavior

Comment: @ssl use `filter(m -> m.getName().equals("None"))` in the filter, and `sorted(Comparator.comparing(Manager::getName)`.

Answer (score 0):

using `sorted` and `partitioningBy`

```
    Map<Boolean, List<String>> partition = names
            .stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy("None"::equals));
    System.out.println(partition);

    List<String> noneFirst = new ArrayList<>(partition.get(true));
    noneFirst.addAll(partition.get(false));
    System.out.println(noneFirst);
```

output

```
[None, Jhon, Nancy, Paul, Robert]
```

Comment: Could replace lambda with method reference: `"None"::equals`.

Comment: Thanks, changed with method reference

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> sorted = names.stream()
                .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1 == null ?
                        -1 :
                        o2 == null ?
                                1 :
                                o1.equals("None") ?
                                        -1 :
                                        o2.equals("None") ?
                                                1 :
                                                o1.compareTo(o2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my contribution: try to make it as good formatted/looking as it can be. 
Notice that this will fail.

```
 List<String> unsorted = ... what-ever ...;
 // ... 
 List<String> sorted = unsorted.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // optional: get rid of nulls before an exception is thrown bellow.
    .sorted((a, b) -> Objects.equals(a, b) ? 0 
                  : "None".equals(a) ? -1
                  : "None".equals(b) ? 1 
                  : a.compareTo(b))
    .distinct()  // optional: if you want to get rid of repeats.
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

```
   names.stream()
                        .sorted((o1, o2) ->
                                {
                                    if("None".equals(o1.getName()) && "None".equals(o2.getName())) return 0;
                                    return "None".equals(o1.getName()) ? -1:
                                            "None".equals(o2.getName()) ? 1 : o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                                }
                        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Sorry but your comparator is not working. Let's try it with a list like `List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Eric", "None", "Paul");` and we'd have the following output `[Eric, None, Paul]`. You cannot return the same thing whether None is s1 or s2 and I don't understand the reason for the second predicate in the if and the else if clauses